# Alphabetical lists in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, list, codeigniter

Wondering how I can do this with CodeIgniter?
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in function to do this.  You'll have to loop through an sql query to do this...

```
Select * from table order by field asc

foreach ( $result as $thing ) {

    if ( $thing['name'][0] != $first_letter) {
        echo '<h2>' . $thing['name'][0] . '</h2>';
        $first_letter = $thing['name'][0];
    }
    echo $result['thing'];

}
```

this is just a rough example...never echo html like that.

Answer (score 0):

1. //in model
   public function alphaDirectory(){ 
   // Query for data
   $sql = "SELECT SUBSTRING(column_name,1,1) AS letter, column_name,column_link FROM table ORDER BY column_name";
   $query = $this->db->query($sql); 
   $columnByName="";

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
 $columnByName[$row->letter][] = array($row->column_name,$row->column_link);
}
return $columnByName;
}

2. //in controller call the model and pass the return array to view
3. in view

     $V){
     echo "
   - ".strtoupper($k)."
       ";
       foreach($v as $links){
        echo "
     - ".$links[0]."
       ";
       }
       echo '
     '
     }
     ?>
4. use css to decorate to get exact match as you are looking